# Javascript- Guided cash payment function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, currency

I'm stuck on a project where we are making financial exercises for children. Each exercise
has a specific objective (Screenshot of an exercise where students match a bill to a numeric amount):

[image: Screenshot here]

One one of the exercises, students add bills to their wallet. Once these bills are added, each user has a wallet array with bills in it as so:

```
var walletArray = [
  {
    code: aed,
    denomination: 0.5,
    image: "/assets/images/coin50",
    type: "coin",
  },
  { code: aed, denomination: 1, image: "/assets/images/coin1", type: "coin" },
  { code: aed, denomination: 5, image: "/assets/images/bill5", type: "bill" },
  { code: aed, denomination: 5, image: "/assets/images/bill5", type: "bill" },
  { code: aed, denomination: 10, image: "/assets/images/bill10", type: "bill" },
  { code: aed, denomination: 50, image: "/assets/images/bill50", type: "bill" },
];
```

I want to write a function that takes an integer input from the user (example: 17) and outputs which bills to pay with. So for this example, if the user inputs 17, the function should output the bills with denominations 5, 5, and 10. I will then calculate the change for them. The website tells the users which bills to pay and how much change they can expect.

I have a function that calculates the total of the wallet array and notifies me if the input amount is greater than the total wallet balance:

```
function calculateTotal(walletArray) {
  total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < walletArray.length; i++) {
    total = total + walletArray[i].denomination;
  }

  if (payAmount > total) {
    console.log("ABOVE LIMIT");
  } else {
    return total;
  }
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to pick the right bills from the array. I'm running a for loop on the array, and its easy enough if the amount input by the user perfectly matches a bill (20 or 50 for example). I just don't know how to select the different bills that the user needs to pay.

```
for (var i = 0; i < walletArray.length; i++) {
  if (payAmount == walletArray[i].denomination) {
    console.log(
      "perfect match! pay with " + currency + walletArray[i].denomination
    );
  } else {
    //code to select the bills goes here
  }
}
```

Any help or even pseudocode to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated. The solution can use vanilla js or any library you like!

Comment: You'll probably want to delete the duplicate entry from the `walletArray`, indices 2 & 3

Comment: Use `map` to create an array of denominations.  Sort this array in descending numerical order (this might require a bit of research, sort is alphabetic not numeric by default; google for examples and they should mention the "comparator" function -- you define this yourself).  Loop over this array of denominations.  And then there's more code on top of that

Comment: @Dexygen the duplicate entries are because two five dollar bills were added. Should I structure the array to have denomination and amount to account for multiples of the same bill?

Comment: How would you define the "right bills for the amount"? What's are the objectives to aim for when selecting the bills?

Comment: @kikon sorry for being unclear. By the right bills I mean the bills that will have the least or no amount of change.

Comment: @kikon I could obviously tell the student to pay for a $17 product with a $50 bill... But that would be inefficient.